# Pygame application runs slower on Mac than on PC

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

A friend and I are making a game in Python (2.7) with the Pygame module. I have mostly done the art for the game so far and he has mostly done the coding but eventually I plan to help code with him once most of the art is done. I am on a Mac (latest version of OS X) and my friend is using a PC.

He has been building and running the game from his PC and as of right now it has been working as planned in his PC (perfect 60fps). However, whenever I pull the code from GitHub (I definitely have the most updated version of our code) and I try to run the game, the game runs like half as fast.

We have tried doubling the fps to 120 in the code and it then runs twice as fast on the PC but when I pull that code on my Mac it still seemed like I was capped around 30fps.

We haven't really found any convincing answers to this problem anywhere else, however we are both pretty new to Pygame and Python so we may be missing something very obvious.

```
import pygame as pg
import os

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

class Wombat:
    def __init__(self, screen_rect, image, starting_loc):
        self.screen_rect = screen_rect
        self.image = image
        self.width = 192
        self.height = 96
        self.starting_loc = starting_loc
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomleft=starting_loc)
        self.speed = 5
        self.grav = .5

        self.jumping = False
        self.y_vel = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.clamp_ip(self.screen_rect)
        self.jump_update()

    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x += x * self.speed
        self.rect.y += y * self.speed

    def jump_update(self):
        if self.jumping:
            self.y_vel += self.grav
            self.rect.y += self.y_vel
            if self.is_touching_ground():
                self.jumping = False

    def is_touching_ground(self):
        return self.rect.y >= self.screen_rect.height - self.height - 50

    def jump(self):
        if not self.jumping:
            self.y_vel = -12
            self.jumping = True


class Control:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screensize = (1000,500)
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(self.screensize, pg.DOUBLEBUF)
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        try:
            self.bg = pg.image.load("res\\bg.png")
            self.wb11 = pg.image.load("res\BlueWombat\BlueStay.png")
            self.wb1 = pg.image.load("res\BlueWombat\BlueWalk.gif").convert_alpha()
            self.wb2 = pg.image.load("res\GreenWombat\GreenStay.png")
            self.wb21 = pg.image.load("res\GreenWombat\GreenWalk.gif")
        except:
            self.bg = pg.image.load("res/bg.png")
            self.wb1 = pg.image.load("res/BlueWombat/BlueStay.png")
            self.wb11 = pg.image.load("res/BlueWombat/BlueWalk.gif")
            self.wb2 = pg.image.load("res/GreenWombat/GreenStay.png")
            self.wb21 = pg.image.load("res/GreenWombat/GreenWalk.gif")
        self.wb2 = pg.transform.flip(self.wb2, True, False)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.fps = 60
        self.quit = False
        self.keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

        self.wombat_one = Wombat(self.screen_rect, self.wb1, (0,450))
        self.wombat_two = Wombat(self.screen_rect, self.wb2, (1000-192,450))

    def run(self):
        while not self.quit:
            now = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.held_keys(self.keys)
            self.event_loop()
            self.update()
            self.render()
            pg.display.update()

            self.clock.tick(self.fps)

    def event_loop(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit = True
            elif event.type in (pg.KEYDOWN, pg.KEYUP):
                self.keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_w:
                        self.wombat_one.jump()
                    if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                        self.wombat_two.jump()

    def held_keys(self, keys):
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.wombat_one.move(-1, 0)
        if keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.wombat_one.move(1, 0)
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.wombat_two.move(-1, 0)
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.wombat_two.move(1, 0)

    def render(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0,0))
        self.wombat_one.render(self.screen)
        self.wombat_two.render(self.screen)

    def update(self):
        self.wombat_one.update()
        self.wombat_two.update()


app = Control()
app.run()
```

Comment: Do you have exactly identical hardware between the PC and the Mac? There are a million factors that could influence this. This isn't really a good questions for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hardware is hardly going to make a difference to code this trivial, is it? In any case, even that doesn't help since Mac drivers tend to be far worse than PC drivers (I get double the framerate from games running under Windows on the same laptop).

Comment: it seems to be in the code though because I can run plenty of legit games like League and Minecraft at 60 fps, and this is a very simple program

Comment: @MorganThrapp - You hit it on the head though. Too many factors involved.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of his specs but my MacBook Pro has 16gb RAM, iris intel pro graphics and a 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7

Comment: I am new to this sorry. Please help me understand how to make this question more answerable

Comment: Might be that you each spent the same amount on your respective computers, in which case the PC could easily run much faster.

Comment: 1. Is his desktop yours a laptop in that case, plug into the wall. 2. Does your machine have enough free'd up cpu's, i.e. do you have some software patch that's hovering in the background, 3. What is your graphics card properties .....it goes on forever. @Robert +10 for Gryffindor that was hilarious

Comment: Look into profile/cProfile. This will at least tell you what the program is busy doing.

Comment: @FirebladeDan today I ran League of Legends (a far more complicated game than this little unfinished project) at 60 fps so it's not my laptop's fault

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hey umm I had the same problem but now my pygame code runs at 60 fps which is good. I am using Idle with Python 3.6.3 and the appropriate pygame for it. Here is how I fixed it:

1. Run your pygame program
2. In the dock you will see a snake with controllers in his mouth. Right click him.
3. Go to Options and click "Show in Finder"
4. Finder will open and you will see a the python application.(Mine was in the shape of rocket with the idle symbol on it.)
5. Right click the python application and click "Get Info".
6. Check the box "Open in Low Resolution" and it should now run at around 60fps.

Comment: Holy crap that did it.

Comment: You saved my life bro :)

Comment: Still helpfull as of 2019* :D Should be accepted answer

Comment: I don't see that option on macOS catalina

Comment: Your a life saver dude, this answer deserves more likes

Comment: Does not work in OSX Catalina unfortunately. Setting the game to full screen via the display options worked for me, but ideally i'd like to not run it in full screen (still haven't figured out a solution to that though).

Comment: I know "thanks! man" comment are unhelpful. But still, you rock. I just can't understand why (the game stays at the same resolution) but this speed it up massively. /I wish I could offer you a bounty or something.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read the documentation for `pygame.time.Clock` and, in particular, this:

> Note that this function uses SDL_Delay function which is not accurate on every platform, but does not use much cpu. Use tick_busy_loop if you want an accurate timer, and don’t mind chewing cpu.

The problem is likely due to issues with `SDL_Delay()` when you're calling `self.clock.tick(self.fps)` in the `run` function.

Comment: I will look into this later. This seems to be getting into what the issue is. Is using "tick_busy_loop" gonna eat up a ton of cpu or just a bit? Our game is just gonna be a little 2D fighting game so I don't want it to eat up a ton of CPU

Comment: I'd say you're better off not using either, personally, and using a tighter control loop of your own.

Comment: how exactly would we do this?