# anaconda python can't set low resolution mode

Tags: python, anaconda, retina

I'm using pygame to write some games on my macbook pro 2018, and using the python in anaconda, the FPS is very low, after some research I found this solution [Pygame application runs slower on Mac than on PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685936/pygame-application-runs-slower-on-mac-than-on-pc), it's says set the python to "Open in Low Resolution", I did the first 5 steps, but the python3.6 in anaconde dose not end with .app, so it doesn't have the "Open in Low Resolution" checkbox, can anyone tell me how to deal with this? many thanks!

Comment: Did you see the other answer in that thread? Do you know for a fact that the code isn't the problem?

Comment: yes, it's not about the code, I just want to know how to set the low resolution, the python from anaconda can't be set as low resolution. I tried to use the build-in python, and it can set low resolution, and also run faster than before.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it,
TLDR

```
pip uninstall pygame
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

seemd the SDL used by pygame can't work correctily on MacBook, and pygame2 use SDL2 that doesn't have that issue